# Advice on executing sequential operations in a non-blocking manner, Task.Run vs task with ContinueWith

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

We have a processor that will receive a queue of elements, and for every element, it will run some actions that need to be guaranteed to be executed in a sequential manner. Each action to execute on an element is a Promise Task (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html). The processing of each element in the queue doesn't need to wait for completion of the previous one.
The signature of the actions can be assumed to be something like this:

```
Task MyAwaitableMethod(int delay)
```

The way I'm seeing, the problem can be reduced to executing a loop, and inside the loop, executing sequential operations, and each iteration shouldn't block. I'm looking at 2 approaches:
1.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    Task.Run(async () => {
            await MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
            await MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
    });
}
```

2.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds).ContinueWith(
        antecedent => MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds));
}
```

I was assuming, given the actions are Promises, that with approach #2, there would be less threads created, as opposed to Task.Run, which I'd assume would create more threads. But in tests I've run, the number of threads created for both when executing a high number of iterations tends to be the same, and not dependent of the given number of iterations.

Are both methods entirely equivalent? Or you guys have better suggestions?

EDIT (rephrasing the question)
Are both methods equivalent in terms of the number of threads both require?

Thanks

Comment: Your second method synchronously runs `MyAwaitableMethod` on the `for` loop's thread till it returns the task, your first approach does not care how long `MyAwaitableMethod` takes to return and returns the wrapping task immediately. The way it does it is by creating a single extra thread.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain...If he did a Parallel.ForEach would that eliminate the blocking and guarantee sequential processing?

Comment: Why not dequeue a batch of tasks, execute them concurrently and asynchronously wait for their completion, then move to the next one? Or, you can simply process them as they get queued. That's a perfect job for TPL Dataflow.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry, didn't quite understood that. I believe the code in the second method is asynchronous, it doesn't wait until it returns the task. Both approaches I understood are returning the wrapping task immediately. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @BigDaddy, YuvalItzchakov: Let's assume it's required the elements in the queue to be processed by the order they arrived (even when we don't really care when they finished). So Parallel.ForEach or concurrent execution wouldn't guarantee this requirement.

Comment: When you call a async method all of the code up to the first `await` in the code will be run by the thread that called the function. If you have a lot of slow code before the first `await` it can significantly slow the system down. Imagine the first line of `MyAwaitableMethod` was `Thread.Sleep(5000)`, your first method would be done likely in under a second, the second method will take at least 5 seconds * `Iterations` because it waits for the first call to `MyAwaitableMethod` to return before continuing to the next loop and `MyAwaitableMethod` takes at least 5 seconds to return.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sorry, didn't explain myself well. We can assume there's nothing blocking in MyAwaitableMethod, they are pure Promise tasks, let's say, the code inside it looks like "return Task.Delay(delay)" (not something that could be a delegate task like Thread.Sleep).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: _"The way it does it is by creating a single extra thread"_ -- IMHO it is probably more correct to say "by creating a single extra task". Whether a new thread is created is up to the runtime. The extra task may or may not result in an additional thread.

Comment: I don't see an actionable problem statement here. Either the question is primarily opinion based (i.e. "which is better") or too broad (i.e. "I have this vague scenario, please discuss"). Since you are not in direct control of threads being created in either scenario, it seems reasonable to me that once you've saturated the thread pool's workload, you're going to see similar thread counts in either scenario (and even a given scenario may experience small variations in thread counts from one test to the next). Is there some actual _problem_ you need help with here?

Comment: @PeterDuniho My question is if Task.Run (await FirstTask; await SecondTask) is entirely equivalent to FirstTask.ContinueWith(SecondTask). My potential problem is, if Task.Run need significantly more threads than the ContinueWith approach.

Comment: The answer to your question is, trivially, of course not. You can look at the code and see that it's not _entirely_ equivalent. The two code examples approach the implementation in fundamentally different ways. As for your potential problem goes, _potential_ problems are not solvable. If you test the code and find an _actual_ problem, that would be solvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`Task.WhenAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    Task t = MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
    tasks.Add(t);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: @PauloMorgado A colleague of mine suggested the same solution as O.O, and explained me some of its details. It looks it wouldn't be parallel because each task will start executing then they are declared. This solution seems to run on the same thread as the caller, seems to answer the best my (poorly formulated) question.

Comment: Only if the tasks are synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the beauty of async-await is to write sequential asynchronous code.

If it was not to be asynchronous, you would write:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
    MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
}
```

If you want it to be asynchronous, just write:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
{
    await MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
    await MyAwaitableMethod(DelayInMilliseconds);
}
```

The code you posted does not satisfy your requirement to process each item only after the previous one because you are not awaiting for `Task.Run`.